# application user authentication java mongodb module

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

I'd naively assume that there's already a package (preferably Java) available for dealing with application level user authentication using mongodb as a backend, but I haven't been able to find one so far. Does one (or more) exist?

To be absolutely clear, I'm not talking about authentication at the mongodb level.

Comment: Did you try to Google "Spring Security MongoDB" or "Shiro MongoDB"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use MongoDB as the authentication Realm for a Java Application.

Now I don't think there's any ready-to-use component that can accomplish that.

What you could do is to handle the DAO layer yourself and provide a the Realm to Apache Shiro, that could handle the authentication.

More on Realms - http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html

You could do the same thing with Spring Security, as it also has ready-to-use DB Realm utilities just for relational databases.

If you want to see some implementations examples, just search for "mongo realm java" or "mongorealm" on Google.

Comment: I haven't checked in much detail, but it seems that http://www.4thex.com/products/camofish/camofish.xhtml could help you.